# I have a php login script which connects to a MySQL Database and my else statement doesn't run

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my back end for the login page it first checks the username against the database if the user exists if checks the password against the user in the data base if they match we log in if they don't we don't log in. And that part works fine however if the username does not exist (and I wrote something that is supposed to catch that) I get a blank white page which is not the intended result. Can someone point out where it is that my code is breaking??

```
<?php

/*
 Handles Login Requests  
*/

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'sec_usr');
define('DB_USER', 'sec_usr');
define('DB_PASS', 'n89tzAh2w3Uf4GUu');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

/*
 $ID=$_POST['user'];
 $Password = $_POST['pass'];
*/

function LogIn()
{
     session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) 
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM username where userName = '$_POST[user]'") or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!empty($row['userName']))
        {
            if($row['userPass'] === $_POST['pass'])
            {
                echo"Success"; /* Works */
            }
            else
            {
                echo"Wrong Pass"; /* Works */
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo"Wrong User"; /* Does Not Work */
        }
    }      
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    LogIn();
}

?>
```

I had added a piece to my question after I had asked the initial question as to how to use the mysqli but my original question which I have reverted the question back to had nothing to do with using mysqli I had figured that if people were telling me to use mysqli I may as well ask those same people how to use it not how to use them together.

Comment: throw this crap out and use mysqli or pdo

Comment: You're not escaping user input in your queries and you're storing unhashed passwords in the database. If you're planning on putting this into production, don't. Use an existing solution that handles user management properly instead.

Comment: To remove the duplicate flag on your question, I suggest you edit it and take out the `mysqli` part that wasn't part of the problem, explain this briefly in the "Edit Summary", then your question can be unmarked (reference: [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)).

Comment: Also, after reading again the link I provided above, I suppose it would be helpful to add a sentence to the end of the question itself explaining that you reverted the edit where you included additional questions about the use of mysqli, rolling back to the original question which doesn't have anything to do with mysqli, thus rendering the duplicate flag for "[Can I use “mysql_” and mysqli together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-use-mysql-and-mysqli-together)" incorrect.

Comment: @MarcosDimitrio thanks for the advice because my question was not intended to be seen as a duplicate just thought that if i was being told use mysqli instead of mysql then those same people may be able to tell me how to adjust my code accordingly to get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out yourself on the comments, the problem is in this part:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

The PHP function `mysql_fetch_array()` returns `FALSE` if there are no rows found. When the user doesn't exist, the query will return `FALSE`, and PHP will execute the part after `or`. The problem is that there is no error for `mysql_error()` to display, since the query executed successfully, that's why you get an empty page.

To fix it, you could do:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($row)
{
    if($row['userPass'] === $_POST['pass'])
    {
        echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong Pass";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Wrong User";
}
```

To be on the safe side, in case you don't receive either the `user` or the `pass` variable, you can also add an Exception in the previous `if`:

```
if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) 
{
    // query the database...
}
else
{
    // Code will most likely not reach here.
    throw new Exception("Form submitted but user/pass not received.");
}
```

Also, be aware that `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM username where userName = '$_POST[user]'")` is open to a SQL injection attack, you must escape the username before using it inside a SQL query. You can read more about it on the [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) page. Can be done like this (taken from that page):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM username where userName = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[user])
);
mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

And last, the [Original MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, it's recommended that you use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension.

Comment: the code right now is just on a private server and will be updated before going live any vulnerabilities are just to make things easier during initial testing

Comment: and I realized my initial problem if the query can't return a row then i get a msqli error so if i take out the or die I get the desired result

Comment: Yes, the problem was the `or die(...)` part, I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `!empty()` check for the query, I'd suggest you use `mysql_num_rows()` to fetch the number of rows and then check if it is greater than 0.

`empty()` returns true if the variable is either `FALSE` or it is not set.

You could try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM username where userName = '$_POST[user]'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($row);
if($num)
{
  \\username exists.
}
else
{
  \\username does not exist.
}
```

EDIT:
Also, I'd advise you move to `mysqli` or `PDO` as they are more secure. Using mysqli won't be very different from mysql except for a few changes but you'd benefit a whole lot more from mysqli than mysql.

**mysql v/s mysqli**

For starters,

```
mysql_connect(host, username, password)
mysql_select_db(db)
```

changes to

```
mysqli_connect(host, username, password, db)
```

and

```
mysql_query(query)
```

changes to

```
mysqli_query(connect, query)
```

So, as you see, there aren't major differences, just minor ones. You could easily shift to mysqli.

**Updated code with mysqli**

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'sec_usr');
define('DB_USER', 'sec_usr');
define('DB_PASS', 'n89tzAh2w3Uf4GUu');

$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error($con));


/*
 $ID=$_POST['user'];
 $Password = $_POST['pass'];
*/

function LogIn()
{
 session_start();
 if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) 
 {
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM username where userName = '$_POST[user]'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($con, $query);
    if($num)
    {
        if($row['userPass'] === $_POST['pass'])
        {
            echo"Success"; /* Works */
        }
        else
        {
            echo"Wrong Pass"; /* Works */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo"Wrong User"; /* Does Not Work */
    }
 }      
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  LogIn();
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm new to using databases how do I use mysqli or PDO?? and how do I get either of them?

Comment: mysqli is just a set of functions very similar to mysql while PDO or PHP Data Objects is a PHP extension. 
If you're new, you should start with mysqli for now. 
I'll edit my answer to add a few differences between mysql and mysqli which should help you.

Comment: is mysqli part of the php code alone or does it involve changes to the database too?

Comment: It is a part of your code. You do not have to make ANY changes whatsoever at your database side in order to use mysqli.

Comment: do I make any changes to how i make an array or get the number of rows?? I have made the change to mysqli and now all I get is wrong user

Comment: thank you for your help with mysqli